# Getting logged in user during App Engine file upload

Tags: java, security, google-app-engine

I'm writing a Google App Engine application that does file uploads to the Blobstore using a form POST and the createUploadUrl method.  In the HttpServlet that handles the upload, UserService.getCurrentUser and getUserPrincipal return null.  The user is logged in and other RemoteServiceServlet calls can retrieve it.  How can I get the logged in user name during the upload?

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails you can send it with your form as a parameter or add the name to a session object which you can retrieve in the handler. But getting the user name like any other place worked for me in a HTTP POST (python) and should work the same using Java.

But anyway you have 3 options:
- The ordinary way *should* work
- If that fails, get the username at the form submit page an post it with the form
- If all else fails, use a session object where you can retrieve the username

The ideal solution is the first and the other two are kind of workarounds since the way you're doing it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I thought of passing the user id but this is for authentication and that doesn't seem secure.  It looks like the post request does not come in with the same session as the others.  Am I missing something that puts all the server requests in the same session?

Comment: What you're trying should work. I can try write a working example if you still don't get it to work. If not familiar with the Java details but I could make it work since I do exactly this with Python and how the API works is quite similar if we look at the Python and Java versions of App engine. In Python I just do get_current_user during HTTP POST in a blobstoreuploadhandler and it works so if you maybe publish your code we can try it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you get this only in the local dev mode. If so, here is the explanation (and a solution): The user is logged in on 127.0.0.1 but the URL returned for the new upload to the blobstore (in the local mode) contains the computer name. As a consequence, the session is broken during the POST redirect from the blobstore to your upload handler, and your service does not recognize the user as being logged in anymore.

Here is a workaround. The method below lives on the server and may be called directly via RPC (from a GWT app), or from a servlet:

```
public String getNewUploadLink() {
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    String url = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/myappname/upload");
    String modifiedUrl = url.replace("ThisIsMyComputerName", "127.0.0.1"); 
    return modifiedUrl;
}
```

You see that it manipulates the URL before returning it to the client. A nicer version would check if the service is running in dev or production mode and then act accordingly, but it highlights the root cause of this problem so that you can continue development on your local machine.